# ATMEL SAMB11/BTLC1000 simple GAP/GATT example

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, atmel

I hope someone could give me a quick example how to configure the BTLE-Device correctly without the huge BLE-Manager library. Simply a litte GAP Authetication and one GATT-Service would be enough to start. I've managed to create my own GATT-Service and characteristics without the need for BLE-Manager but thanks to several defines, typedefs etc. I can't figure out how to do this for GAP and how to register my callbacks for it. Maybe someone has used these modules before and can give me a quick example how it's done?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned One GATT-Service with Authentication Atmel-BAS [Battery Service] example is easy one. To better understand you can download the getting started guide see the architecture. In-order to register the callbacks you need to check the order of callbacks in function ble_event_manager in ble_manager.c file.

Comment: Now the callbacks are registered in the type of structure. you don't need to check order of the callback.